# Incomplete scan of bluetooth devices

Tags: android

I am trying to scan for bluetooth devices using a processing based android app. I would like to use processing to communicate to my microcontroller board via bluetooth as shown in the example below:

http://webdelcire.com/wordpress/archives/1045

I was successful in launching this app on my android tablet. However, I am not able to list the bluetooth device on my tablet. The only bluetooth device that my tablet recognizes is the bluetooth adapter on my computer. Why am I not able to list all the bluetooth devices? My computer is able to recognize the microcontroller's bluetooth device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your embedded target board identifies itself erroneously as a Bluetooth Device.
The computer's Bluetooth adapter accepts this error, while Android does not.

**If** you can change the **SDP records** (*Bluetooth search discovery protocol*) of the embedded target board, maybe Android will see the device (try making it look as a headset or hands free device!).

The quick way is to **change the 'magic numbers'** defining the SDP class, service id, etc. The numbers are inside [this](https://www.bluetooth.org/Technical/AssignedNumbers/service_discovery.htm) document. Then see if Android sees your board.

---

You can also read the [Bluetooth Core Spec](http://www.bluetooth.org/Building/HowTechnologyWorks/CoreSpecifications.htm) if you have the time.

See [this](http://www.palowireless.com/infotooth/tutorial/sdp.asp#PDU%20Format) tutorial for more on the formal aspects, and "Bluetooth for programmers" for a lighter introduction.

Comment: I found the problem. The app was not looking for new devices, otherwise known as the discovery option. Now I am able to scan for bluetooth devices